# Set as Wallpaper

Tags: android

I am able to change wallpaper of device , but I want an user to gibe option when click on set wallpaper button , ie either he want to set image as home screen or for whatsapp or for facebook .

here is my working method for setting wallpaper:

```
    fullImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFullscreen);

public void setAsWallpaper(Bitmap bitmap) {
        try {
            WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(_context);

            wm.setBitmap(bitmap);
            Toast.makeText(_context,
                    _context.getString(R.string.toast_wallpaper_set),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(_context,
                    _context.getString(R.string.toast_wallpaper_set_failed),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

and this click method code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) fullImageView.getDrawable())
                .getBitmap();

        switch (v.getId()) {
        // button Download Wallpaper tapped
        case R.id.llDownloadWallpaper:
            utils.saveImageToSDCard(bitmap);
            break;
        // button Set As Wallpaper tapped
        case R.id.llSetWallpaper:

            utils.setAsWallpaper(bitmap);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }
```

Working code would be very much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void setImageAsWallpaperPicker(Uri path) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    MimeTypeMap map = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    String mimeType = map.getMimeTypeFromExtension("png");
    intent.setDataAndType(path, mimeType);
    intent.putExtra("mimeType", mimeType);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set as"));
}
```

Comment: Do I need to replace my existing code from this ..I am new to android

Comment: yes, if you want to pop out a popup and select what you want to do with the path, like set as wallpaper, or set as whatsapp profile ,etc.